# How to change the selected option value using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

There is a dropdown box on the web page with code:

```
<select 
name="ctl00$ctl05$ddlCurrency" 
id="ctl00_ctl05_ddlCurrency" 
class="ddlCurrency" 
style="font-size:x-small;width: 55px; background-color: #EDEEEF;">
    <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="GBP" selected="selected">GBP</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
</select>
```

Please, tell me how to change the selected option value "GBP" to value "USD" of a dropdown box in an IE window using vbscript?

Thanks,

Pers2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://www.example.com/"
While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

For Each opt In ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl05_ddlCurrency").Options
  If opt.Value = "USD" Then
    opt.Selected = True
  Else
    opt.Selected = False
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately… no

Comment: I had the code check for `GBP` instead of `USD`. Try again. If it still doesn't work for you, you need to provide more information about how the results are different from what you expect.

Comment: Wow, it's fantastic… all is splendid. Thank you very much‼! 
Only in this: ie.Navigate http://www.example.com/ without “=”